# Get all questions with 1 or more upvotes without answers sorted by new

Tags: support, questions, search

Is it possible to get a list of questions by the following criteria:

- have 1 or more upvotes
- no answers have been posted
- has tags A or B or C
- sorted by new

Comment: No -- comments are not searchable, nor is the presence of them.

Comment: I don't think the OR bit of the tags is possible, either.

Comment: But for the rest, something like: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=score%3a1..%20is%3aquestion%20answers%3a0%20%5ba%5d%5bb%5d

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
is:question score:1 answers:0 [A] or [B] or [C]
```

- `is:question` narrows results down to just questions.
- `score:1` will return posts with a score greater than or equal to 1.
- `answers:0` will return questions with no answers.
- To combine results from multiple tags, separate the tag names (enclosed in square brackets) with the word `or`.
- Select the `newest` tab.

For more reference, visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching).

Comment: Sometimes you have to explicitly write `score:1..`. Just pay attention to the right side of a search page where every search option is listed.

Comment: @Xufox In which case? You use `..` after the number to make it `>=`, which is by default.

Comment: Ok, I’ve tried it again and it appears that `score:1` and all other non-zero numbers are interpreted as `>= 1` but only `score:0` as `= 0`.